# RFC-822 DateTime Formatting in PHP with Database

Tags: php, date

I have a date field on my database. the date format as following.

```
June 17, 2013
```

Im using the format as

```
date("F j, Y");
```

So my question is there a way that i can display this date in RFC-822 format using php? or do i need to start saving the date in RFC-822 format from now on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you save the dates as ... dates? I.e., change the DB field to a date type and save yourself from conversions. Existing values can be easily parsed into "real" dates.

Comment: What is your field type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither.

From now on you have to start using *[format supplied by database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)*.
You have to understand the difference between storage format and display formatting. It's different matters. When storing data in mysql, you have to follow mysql rules. So, instead of `June 17, 2013` you have to store `2013-06-17`.

And then convert at output to whatever format required - not limited to a single one but whatever format is demanded by destination.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I will start to store in such manner from now on.

Comment: Could've phrased it a bit more politely.

Answer (score 8):

Using the following syntax, you can display current time in RFC822 Format.

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $date->format(DateTime::RFC822);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to date format something in PHP for [**RFC-822**](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z28) , then just do this...

```
date('r', strtotime($date))
```

> `'r'`  » RFC 2822 formatted date   Example: Thu, 21 Dec 2000 16:01:07 +0200

Source: [**PHP.net: DateFormat**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

*But, as other stated, you don't want to store this in your database!*  However, you'll need to use `r` for other things, like XML-RSS date time formats...

> All date-times in RSS conform to the Date and Time Specification of RFC 822... (Source: [**RSS 2.0 Specification**](https://www.rssboard.org/rss-2-0).)

Comment: `$this->_add_hdr('Date', sprintf(date('r', strtotime($date))));` produces the: `Date: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00  0100` idea please?

Answer (score 3):

None of the other answers worked for me, so this is what worked... to take a date in PHP and output it in RFC822:

```
date("D, d M Y G:i:s T", strtotime($date));
```

Hope that helps others.

Comment: Feed wouldn't [validate](https://www.feedvalidator.org/) until I adjusted you example as per [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php): 

'date('D, d M Y H:i:s O',strtotime($date))'

Comment: Almost perfect, just change the G: to H: to get a leading zero on the hour.

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out your best bet is to change the way you are storing your dates to something other then a string.  `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date))` can assist you in this endeavor.

But to solve the immediate need you can utilize use strtotime, date and the DATE_RFC822 constant to get you what you are looking for.

```
echo date(DATE_RFC822, strtotime($value));
```

See First example on [php date documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 2):

As @ashleedawg and others mentioned in some comments the simplest solution that works:

```php
date("D, d M Y H:i:s O", strtotime($date));
```

Mind the "H" and the "O" ;)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

date_format(date(your database field), '%D, %j %M %t')

and what type of format you want just see the link
[date and time format for Mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as TimeStamp in database and  show it RFC822 format

```
date(DATE_RFC822, time());
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as the RSS validator doesn't accept the 2-digit year. Year has to be 4 digits.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that worked for me:

```
date("D, d M Y H:i:s T", strtotime($date));
```

Other examples above that didn't work include using the DATE_RFC822 format specifier, which puts out a 2-digit year, instead of 4 digits. Then the other suggestion to use G:i:s for time doesn't work because G specifies no leading zeroes, so you'll get 2:00:00 instead of 02:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

don't use T at the end but an "O", it works for me

Comment: This looks more like a comment to other answer(s) rather than a new answer.